# php sessions with iis, memcached or ramdisk?

Tags: php, iis, memcached

I need a stable solution storing session data in ram on a MS/IIS7.

Single server setup.

Thankful for any experiences regarding

- http://splinedancer.com/memcached-win32/
- regular ramdisk and just altering session_save_path.

Comment: Stable? Go for the file-system, and if it's too slow for you, switch to SSD or RAMDISK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on your current and future scalability requirements. Any setup of the 3 you mentioned is sure going to be stable. Whether it will be sufficient for your requirements or not; is another question.

Good news is that at any point in time you can switch your strategy from in memory to distributed sessions (if you plan to add more servers) by simply installing the memcache session extension for php.

Therefore I would recommend you to not worry about it now and simply use in memory sessions unless you need to scale out.